# Change title and button size for search bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I want to change the name's button from seaarch bar , i found some examples and the one which it's works is this :

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    UIButton *cancelButton;


    UIView *topView = self.search.subviews[0];
    for (UIView *subView in topView.subviews) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UINavigationButton")]) {
            cancelButton = (UIButton*)subView;
        }
    }
    if (cancelButton) {
        [cancelButton setTitle:@"Annuler" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cancelButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    }
    return  YES;
}
```

but the problem is this : when i start editing , firstly "cancel" it's showed and after  annuler appears. The font size is 12 only for cancel .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i change the name of button from search bar :CANCEL to ANNULER

```
 UIBarButtonItem *searchBarButton = [UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil];
    [searchBarButton setTitle:@"Annuler"];
```